# mod_rewrite in XAMPP and Magento 2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I followed this tutorial http://www.appseconnect.com/how-to-install-magento-2-on-xampp-server-localhost/ to install Magento 2 on XAMPP (Windows).

But, after install magento, I open the project and admin on browser and when I see the firebug console there countless errors when trying to access js, css and fonts of the folder pub/static:

[image]

I tried this solution (and a few others I found on google) but not resolved.

Comment: What did you define as your document root folder?

Comment: my root folder is C:\xampp\htdocs and my project is C:\xampp\htdocs\{project} @PanamaJack

Answer (score 0):

- Set the Magento 2 mode to 'Developer mode.
- Clear everything on pub/static folder except .htaccess file.
- Also clear all cache (var/cache/* , var/page_cache/* ,
  var/generation/*)
- Check folder permission of 'pub/static' folder.
- Refresh the page on browser.

  In 'Developer mode' required files will automatically create on
  public/static folder if the folder have permission to create files.